# How to pass proxy-authentication to python Requests module

Tags: python, authentication, proxy, python-requests

I'm working on existing python code that uses the **request** module to perform get/post towards a web site.

The python code also allow the use of proxies when a proxy is passed to the script otherwise no proxies are used.

My problem regards the use of proxies that requires **authentication**.

```
proxy = user:password@ip:port
self.s = requests.Session()
if proxy != "":
      self.proxies = {
        "http": "http://" + proxy,
        "https": "https://" + proxy
      }
      self.s.proxies.update(proxies)

self.s.get('http://checkip.dyndns.org')
```

In the code above, if the proxy is configured each **get** is refused because no authentication is provided.

I found a solution that implies the use of HTTPProxyAuth.

This is the solution that I found:

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()

proxies = {
  "http": "http://ip:port",
  "https": "https://ip:port"
}

auth = HTTPProxyAuth("user", "pwd")
ext_ip = s.get('http://checkip.dyndns.org', proxies=proxies, auth=auth)
print ext_ip.text
```

My question is: is it possibile to set the proxy authorization globally instead of modify each **s.get** in the code? Because sometime the script could be used without proxy and sometimes with proxy.

Thanks in advance!

Best Regards,
Federico

Comment: Your session object needs a proxy detail so you can use s.proxies=proxies

Comment: @NishantPatel yes but regarding the authorization? I also need to specify user and password for the proxy.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found the solution, about how to set proxy authentication globally:

```
import requests
import urllib2
import re
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth

s = requests.Session()

proxies = {
  "http": "http://185.165.193.208:8000",
  "https": "https://185.165.193.208:8000"
}

auth = HTTPProxyAuth("gRRT7n", "NMu8g0")

s.proxies = proxies
s.auth = auth        # Set authorization parameters globally

ext_ip = s.get('http://checkip.dyndns.org')
print ext_ip.text
```

BR,
Federico

Comment: You should mark this answer as a solution to the question, if it resolved it.

Comment: this code not need to import 2 library : `import urllib2` and  `import re`

Comment: `HTTPProxyAuth` represents basic authentication. This won't work for proxies that demand others authentication schemes.